# Multi line comma separated list in JSon -Parse with Python

Tags: python, json

I have a json file which I was parsing to read some attributes which looks like below.

```
"controls": {
"PS": {
      "name": "Physical Security",
      "level_name": [
        "PS 1",
        "PS 2"
      ],
      "cost": [
        6,
        10
      ],
      "ind_cost": [
        2,
        2
      ],
      "flow": [
        0.55,
        0.325
      ]
    },
.
.
.
}
```

Previously when I had only one level like only "PS 1" there was no problem and I was reading the values using this code.

```
 for control in data['controls']: 
        print(control,': ', data['controls'][control]['name'])
```

Now, having more than one levels I am having difficulty. I tried to split as below.

```
 x = data['controls'][control]['name'].split('\n')
```

or as below

```
 x = data['controls'][control]['name'].split(',')
```

or as below

```
 x = data['controls'][control]['name'].split('\n,')
```

Each time I get only one item in x, for this example PS.

What I want is to be able to get PS 1 and PS 2 in this order. Later, I will apply it to cost and other things..
Thanks in advance.

Ferda

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using:

```
 x = data['controls'][control]['name'].split('\n')
```

Since you used this loop:

```
 for control in data['controls']:
```

control isn't the name, as control refers to:

```
data['controls'][---]
```

as an object, thus if you want to use it, you should instead use:

```
x = control['name'].split('\n')
```

Assuming no other issues in the code, this should work. Let me know if you face any issues with that!

Edit 1:

Noting the error mentioned, control was told to be a string, however this means one of two things:

1. the JSON isn't parsed correctly due to some error in the format:

Thinking of this, it would mean that control would include all the JSON inside it e.g.

```
print(control)

Output: "name": "Physical Security",
          "level_name": [
            "PS 1",
            "PS 2"
          ],
          "cost": [
            6,
            10
          ],
          "ind_cost": [
            2,
            2
          ],
          "flow": [
            0.55,
            0.325
          ]
        },
```

Option 2) You need to re-parse your result

I can't think of why/if this would happen, but if you have a valid JSON as your output you might just simply need to re-parse it the same way you parsed the original (I assume you are using the standard JSON libary?)

Comment: When I write it like that I get "TypeError: string indices must be integers" error..

Comment: Can you do "print(data['controls'])" so I have an idea of what's that outputing? @Ferda-Ozdemir-Sonmez

Comment: This is part of a research, I can not share all the list and it is very long. The json looks exactly as it is shown in the sample. Assume you have this Physical Security and some other controls with one or more levels.

Comment: So, if you have a string that means that the JSON isn't recognized as further JSON after that control, but as text, hence why I want to see what that looks like. Your options then would be either to investigate why the JSON isn't being recognized further as JSON and considering if you can edit it (e.g. maybe you have the wrong kind of bracket? I can't tell without seeing the data directly), or a brute-force solution would be a few lines of manual recognition (e.g. dealing with that string manually, or re-parsing it). control here should be an object or a long string you need to parse further.

Comment: No, I have never said that this is not recodnized as json. In fact I parse it using a json parser. As a part of that parsa I get the data, data[controls] etc...

Comment: The error "TypeError: string indices must be integers" indicates that controls is being detected as a string instead of a json object, thus you cannot access an inner object. The main object "data" is read as json, but components of data["controls"] are for some reason not.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake, I used name instead of level_name. The below code solved my problem.

```
x = data['controls'][control]['level_name']
        
        
        for control_level in x:
```